# FormBuilder.js: How to inherit from radio-group control?

Tags: javascript, formbuilder

I'm trying to create a new control for FormBuilder, it's basically a radio-group control (I mean it has the same config of a radio-group control) but I need to define a custom build() and onRender() method.

I read docs a lot of times but can't get it to work, here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
if (!window.fbControls) window.fbControls = new Array();
window.fbControls.push(function (controlClass) {

  class controlMultipleObjects extends controlClass {

    static get definition() {
      return {
        icon: '\uD83D\uDD89',
        i18n: {
          default: 'Control Multiple Items'
        }
      };
    }

    configure() {
      // this.js = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js';
    }

    /**
     * build a text DOM element, supporting other jquery text form-control's
     * @return DOM Element to be injected into the form.
     */
    build() {

      this.dom = this.markup('div', null, {class:'multipleObjectsController', id: this.config.name});

      return this.dom;
    }

    onRender() {
    }
  }

  // register this control for the following types & text subtypes
  controlClass.register('multipleObjects', controlMultipleObjects);
  return controlMultipleObjects;
});
```

This basically works, the new control 'multipleObjects' is shown in form builder, but when opening the config for the control it only shows the 'Value' item. I need to show multiple values just like the radio-group, select or select-group controls.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://formbuilder.online/docs/formBuilder/options/typeUserAttrs

you'll need to pass options in your formBuilder like that:

```
const options = {
    typeUserAttrs: {
        multipleObjects: {
            options: {
                label: 'Class',
                multiple: true,
                options: {
                    'red form-control': 'Red',
                    'green form-control': 'Green',
                    'blue form-control': 'Blue'
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

$("#fb-editor").formBuilder(options)
```